# MQTT communication for IOT devices with cloud Server

Tags: http, mqtt, iot

I'm designing  a system where there will be 100,000 appliances and user will be able to send/receive data to his appliance over MQTT. 
Device to App communication: 
There will be a mac address based unique topic and device ID of each appliance . Each appliance will publish its data to topic of the server . The server will send the data to corresponding App over HTTP.

App to Device communication 
The App will send data to server over HTTP and server will forward  the data to corresponding appliance over MQTT.

Now can you please guide me is this a correct way to do that ? or a better way is server should subscribe to unique topics of all appliances ?

Following is the flow diagram for the above mentioned procedure

[image]

Comment: You should allow the user to use it's IoT device without connecting to public internet or cloud servers. You will build security problems into your system, you will leak privacy of users and risk their devices. You will allow 100k more sytems to be part of a botnet.

Comment: You are right as far as security is concerned. For now I have used HTTPS to ensure safer communication and will look into the improvements i can make.

Comment: You are going to build a massive bottleneck with such an architecture. Some MQTT Brokers can handle up to hundreds of thousands of msg/sec, your single server in the backend won't be able to handle such a load. Consider using shared subscriptions or a broker plugin for HTTP. If you're in the cloud, clustering (with load balancers in front) for HA and scalability may be worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

IBM Bluemix offers an [IoT for electronics](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/IotElectronics/index.html) service which may be of interest to you.  It uses the Watson IoT Platform to connect your smart electronic appliances with the applications that you develop. It also helps you analyze and understand the data from your appliances.

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion. I am looking into this. However, my concern is also to get a better understanding of the MQTT standards. I have worked with an architecture in which the cloud server had one topic to which every device could publish to. Another way of doing it is that the server should subscribe to all the unique device topics. and listen what ever is communicated to and from the device.
Can you please suggest which system would perform better

Comment: With IBM's Watson IoT Platform, each device has its own unique topic space.  The subscriber to read the info can use wildcards to check for a number of topics.

Answer (score 1):

You can send and receive messages with [Azure IoT hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging#communication-protocols) that supports MQTT and HTTP protocols, with device-to-cloud and cloud-to-device capabilites.

[Azure IoT device SDKs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks) can be used with a broad range of OS platforms and devices. You can build your "device" and "App" with [Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/csharp/device) .

You can deploy MQTT broker in Azure, [this](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/hivemq-on-windows-azure-mqtt-microsoft-cloud) and [this](http://www.embedded101.com/Blogs/PaoloPatierno/entryid/455/gnatmq-in-the-cloud-an-mqtt-broker-on-microsoft-azure) you can reference.

The [throughput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-scaling) varies with the service tier, up to 208,333 messages per minute.